# Crystal get from n line to n line from a file

Tags: crystal-lang

How can I get specific lines in a file and add it to array?

For example: I want to get lines 200-300 and put them inside an array. And while at that count the total line in the file. The file can be quite big.

Answer (score 6):

[`File.each_line`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2/File.html#each_line%28filename%3APath%7CString%2Cencoding%3Dnil%2Cinvalid%3Dnil%2Cchomp%3Dtrue%2C%26%29-class-method) is a good reference for this:

```
lines = [] of String
index = 0
range = 200..300

File.each_line(file, chomp: true) do |line|
  index += 1
  if range.includes?(index) 
    lines << line
  end
end
```

Now `lines` holds the lines in `range` and `index` is the number of total lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent reading the entire file and allocating a new array for all of its content, you can use [File.each_line](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/File.html#each_line%28filename%2Cencoding%3Dnil%2Cinvalid%3Dnil%2Cchomp%3Dtrue%2C%26block%29-class-method) iterator:

```
lines = [] of String

File.each_line(file, chomp: true).with_index(1) do |line, idx|
  case idx
  when 1...200  then next          # ommit lines before line 200 (note exclusive range)
  when 200..300 then lines << line # collect lines 200-300
  else break                       # early break, to be efficient
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not count the total number of lines.

Comment: @felixbuenemann you're right, i misread that part of the question.